# Javascript: Unshift() is causing an infinite loop but can't see why

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function that takes an array and returns the array with the even numbers before the odd numbers.  I figured I'd iterate through the array and check the divisibility of each number with modulo.  If it's an even number, I unshift that number to the front of the array and keep going.

I've removed unshift to log that it iterates through so I know the issue isn't with my loop.

```
/// A = [3,5,6,3,4,2,1]

var sortArrayByParity = function(A) {
    for (var x =0; x< A.length;x++) {
        if (A[x] % 2 == 0) {
           A.unshift(A[x])
        } 
    }
    return A;
};
```

Maximum stack error is occuring.

Comment: *"I am trying to make a function that takes an array and returns the array with the even numbers before the odd numbers"* So you want to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the Array. like this? `A.sort((a,b) => (a&1) - (b&1));`

Comment: @Thomas awesome, didn't think of bitwise operators.   Having looked at the documentation for sort, I see this works but I have no idea why: n.sort(function(a, b) { return a % 2 - b % 2 || a - b; });    What is having that return even numbers first?

Comment: `a&1` returns the lowest bit of a number, which determines whether the number is even or odd (binary numbers ending with 0 are even, those ending with 1 are odd). Keep in mind that this method will not work for large numbers, `a%2` is generally safer to use.

Comment: @Kresimir thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 5):

Because `unshift` adds an element to the array, thereby increasing its `length`.  Furthermore, once the `unshift` adds an element to the beginning of the array, the next `A[x]` is the same as the previous one, as all elements get moved to the right, including `x`. So the loop never finishes, because the index `x` never reaches the ever increasing `length`.

If you need to add elements to an array through which you are iterating with a loop, it's better to do it with `push` in a loop that counts downwards from `length` to `0`. That way, the loop will never iterate through added elements, and the elements that it will iterate through will not move.

Answer (score 0):

When you unshift an array an element is added to the start of that array and increase the length.

Lets try

```js
let arr = [1];
console.log('arr = ',arr, 'length =',  arr.length);
arr.unshift(0);
console.log('arr = ',arr, 'length =',  arr.length);
```

As a result when you find a even number you unshift it to the front but it will also be available in x + 1 position. and as you iterate you will find the same even number in next iteration.

correct implementation would be.

```js
/// A = [3,5,6,3,4,2,1]

var sortArrayByParity = function(A) {
    for (var x =0; x< A.length;x++) {
        if (A[x] % 2 == 0) {
           A.unshift(A[x]);
           A.splice(x+1, 1);
        } 
    }
    return A;
};

console.log(sortArrayByParity([3,5,6,3,4,2,1]));
```

You should use both [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) and [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).