# Sort the numbers so that the even numbers were ahead

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array with 20 random numbers (from -10 to 10) , I need to sort them . The even numbers must be in front of array. like let arr = [-2,3,6,-12,9,2,-4,-11,-8]  must become  arr = [-12,-8,-2,2,4,6,-11,3,9]
here is my code:

```
let array = Array(20).fill().map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 20) - 10);

console.log(array);

function moveEvenToFront(array){
    let temp=0;
    let a=0;
    for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){

        if(array[i] % 2 == 0){

            for (let j=i; j>a; j-- ){

                temp = array[j-1];

                array[j-1] = array[j];

                array[j] = temp;

            }
            a++;
        }

    }
    return array;
}

moveEvenToFront(array);
```

I tried this function , but it doesn't works.

Comment: Not entirely clear what expected results are. Can you provide example?

Comment: Basically the same thing has been asked yesterday over here: [Javascript: Unshift() is causing an infinite loop but can't see why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898315/javascript-unshift-is-causing-an-infinite-loop-but-cant-see-why) is this some kind of homework?

Comment: does it need to work "in place" like this?  why not just create a new array, do one pass appending all the even numbers, then another pass appending all the odd numbers…

Comment: "it doesn't works" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `.sort()` method and a comparator. The comparator function will have to first check the "evenness" of the two arguments. If they're both even or both odd, it'll then base the comparison result on the value:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  let aeven = !(a % 2), beven = !(b % 2);
  if (aeven && !beven) return -1;
  if (beven && !aeven) return 1;
  return a - b;
});
```

A comparator function for the `.sort()` method is passed two values from the array. The function should return:

- a negative number if the first should sort *before* the second;
- a positive number if the first should sort *after* the second;
- zero if they're the same for ordering purposes.

Comment: Shorter syntax also possible: `arr.sort((a, b) => (!(b % 2) - !(a % 2)) || a - b)`.

Comment: @Jeto yes that's certainly true, though It's not quite as clear :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a group for sorting even and odd numbers and then sort by value with a chained approach.

```js
function sort(array) {
    return array.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(a) % 2 - Math.abs(b) % 2 || a - b)
}

console.log(sort(Array.from({ length: 20 }, _ => Math.round(Math.random() * 20) - 10)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Jeto, right, it needs absoplute value for taking the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
let array = Array(20).fill().map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 20) - 10);


    function moveEvenToFront(array) {
        console.log(array);

        const tempEven = array.filter(el => {return el % 2 === 0});
        const tempOdd = array.filter(el => {return el % 2 !== 0});

    const tempEvenSorted = tempEven.sort((a, b) => {
        return a - b;
    });

    const tempOddSorted = tempOdd.sort((a, b) => {
        return a - b;
    });

    return tempEvenSorted.concat(tempOddSorted);

    }

     console.log(moveEvenToFront(array));
```

A combination of filter() and sort(). First filter the evens and then the odds into different arrays. Then sort them separately and then add them together.

The `sort()` function takes two arguments which are elements from your original array and must return a negative number, a positive number or zero and based on that creates a new sorted array and returns it.

Comment: That doesn't sort the values on their value however.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the question right the first time. Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

```
function moveEvenToFront(array) {
    let evenIndex = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
            // Swapping the current element with the element at evenIndex
            let temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[evenIndex];
            array[evenIndex] = temp;
            evenIndex++;
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```